# Data Binding ionic checkbox in controller not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Is my firts time working with ionic and angular. I have a checkbox list populate from controller, when I click on check the view show my change but if I want view this change on controller show me the old value. I need add/substract the values

html

```
   <div class="item-text-wrap">
     <ion-list>
         <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="item in listTypeProduct"
         ng-model="item.checked" 
         ng-checked="item.checked"
         ng-change="add(listTypeProduct)" >{{ item.text }}
    </ion-checkbox>

      </ion-list>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <pre ng-bind="listTypeProduct | json"></pre> 
    </div>
```

the print on page is working!

[image: when I click on check the binding working]

This is my controller

```
 app.controller('CotCtrl', function($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate,$rootScope) {

$scope.listTypeProduct = [
         { text: "a1",    checked: false , value:4500 },
         { text: "a2",  checked: false , value:2000 },
         { text: "a3", checked: false , value:1200 }
];

$scope.add = function(list){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(list));
};
```

But on my controller when I iterate the array give me the old information.

[image]

Method "add" I want iterate the list with update values for example

```
angular.forEach(list, function(val, key) {
 if( checked && (value) )
   $scope.total += total+val.value;
 });
```

To add all  checked values.

Comment: the solution was replace <ion-chexkbox by input type='checkbox' and working!

Answer (score 0):

Quoting AngularJS documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked)

> Note that this directive "ngChecked" should not be used together with ngModel, as this can lead to unexpected behaviour.

This said, use only ng-model to bind your checkbox to the model in the controller.